# Cordova advanced http plugin shows HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED when download file with SSLCertMode set to 'nocheck'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-native-http

I'm developing an Ionic v3 application, the Android app download files using cordova advanced http plugin. The server uses https.

I use setSSLCertMode('nocheck'). However when calling downloadFile I'm getting error: stream is reset HTTP_1_1_REQUIRED.

The server is running ASP.NET WebApi.

```
this.http.setSSLCertMode('nocheck');
this.http.downloadFile(url, {}, headers, fileName);
```

Comment: add code. how you are doing ?

Comment: which version of ionic framework ?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari, please see my updated question.